# Simple configurable Express middleware not executing

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to build a [configurable middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) (a custom middleware function that takes custom parameters, and returns a `(req,res,next)` function that uses these parameters) in Express. However, I can't get this middleware to execute on a `router.get()` call.

The expected behaviour in the code below is that, when trying to GET the home page (/), the console logs 'success!' then I get a 404 (as the `next()` in the middleware will pass me on to the 404 function).

However, nothing happens and the request times out. The function is being detected, as when I put the `console.log()` in the middleware but just before the `return function(req,res,next){` line, I am seeing the output on the console. I only get this issue when the configurable middleware is *returning* a function.

**./app.js** *(no changes to the template that Express builds):*

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**./routes/index.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var simplemiddleware = require('../middlewares/simplemiddleware');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  simplemiddleware.simpleReturn('success!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**./middlewares/simplemiddleware.js**:

```
exports.simpleReturn = function (outputString){
  return function (req,res,next) {
    console.log(outputString);
    next();
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the

```
var simplemiddleware = require('../middlewares/simplemiddleware');
```

actually is a `function`, to fix the problem, please try the following.

**./routes/index.js:**

```
var simplemiddleware = require('../middlewares/simplemiddleware');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  // note `simplemiddleware.simpleReturn(str)` returns a function
  let func = simplemiddleware.simpleReturn('success!');

  // run the middleware
  func(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Beautiful, and clear explanation. Thank you Neverever!